# Do DJs ever use a third track to keep a third kick going for several songs or even entire sets? Or is the effect of "silkiness" achieved another way?

Tags: performing, production, dj, bass-drum

I listen to a *lot* of a specific genre, progressive house, but one DJ in particular, Hernan Cattaneo, seems to achieve a "silkiness" in his bass drum during transitions (or maybe it just stands out to me during transitions). For example, the first few transitions of his recent set at [Forja centro Eventos](https://soundcloud.com/hightensionds/hernan-cattaneo-dia-1-forja-centro-eventos-05-10-2019) around 5m00s, 13m00s, 27m00s, etc.

The first few times I noticed this, I thought it was just subjective error or my mind overlaying a past experience based on recognizing the DJ's name. But I've noticed this in many sets over several years, so I wonder if Hernan does something special.

Does he keep a few choice bass drum samples on a third track and use it during transitions, or maybe even entire tracks? This is unlikely, because then he'd have to cut out that third track whenever the main track(s) cut out, right? (Or maybe it's possible to use a bass drum "trigger" to trigger that third track?) Or is it more likely he's using some kind of effect (like a mastering preset) that does this?

Can any experienced DJs weigh in on what's the likely explanation / technique? Have you seen any DJs use a third track in this way? Does it sound like a certain effect to you?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using a third channel as a loop bed to be used as a foundation for decks 1 &  2 transitions is not uncommon. The fluid transitions are the result of  EQ mixing. Which can be done by gradually  cutting out the mid band on a 3 or 4 band mixer from the playing track and gradually bringing in the mid band from the incoming track. There are other aspects of EQ mixing by cutting different bands to avoid kick drum phasing ( kick drums canceling out each other creating an unwanted flanging effect)

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Did you perhaps mean "not **common**"? But I think you're right, now that I think of it, cutting the mid does produce kind of that "silky" effect (at least for me).

Comment: Woops, I see (after a little experience now) that you did mean not _uncommon_.